# XPath: Get certain nodes and the ancestors

Tags: xslt, xpath

From the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<bookstore>
<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book>
  <title lang="de">Vom Winde verweht</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

I want all books that have lang="eng" *and* their ancestor nodes, i.e. the following output:

```
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

How do I obtain this using XPath?

**EDIT:** If my description and sample output doesn't match due to poor terminology, the sample describes what I want.

Comment: XPath is a *query* language over XML documents. As such, it is not possible as result of the evaluation of an XPath expression to alter existing documents or to create a new document/node. What you are asking for is the creation of a new XML document from the current one -- this is a *transformation* and cannot be done in XPath alone. XSLT is a language most appropriate for performing XML document transformations. It is trivial to produce the wanted document with XSLT. Are you interested in an XSLT solution?

Answer (score 1):

This should return all the books that have English somewhere inside:

```
/bookstore/book[.//@lang="eng"]
```

The ancestor of the book is `bookstore` that contains everything. Are you sure you want it back, too?

Comment: This doesn't match the elements in the provided sample output.

Comment: You can just add `/ancestor-or-self::*` at the end. This will not return what is shown as the sample output, though.

Answer (score 1):

**XPath is a query language over XML documents**.

As such, it is not possible as result of the evaluation of an XPath expression to alter existing documents or to create a new document/node.

What you are asking for is the creation of a new XML document from the current one -- this is a *transformation* and cannot be done in XPath alone. XSLT is a language most appropriate for performing XML document transformations. It is trivial to produce the wanted document with XSLT.

**Are you interested in an XSLT solution?  Here is one**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="book[not(title/@lang = 'eng')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<bookstore>
<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book>
  <title lang="de">Vom Winde verweht</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<bookstore>
   <book>
      <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
   </book>
</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description doesn't quite match your sample output. I've gone with your sample:

```
/bookstore/book[./title/@lang='eng']/ancestor-or-self::*
|/bookstore/book[./title/@lang='eng']/descendant::*
```

A union of the book + ancestors and the book's descendants.